# QGIS: group labels from different lines below each other instead side by side

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have the following problem. I have a Linestring layer in QGIS.
There are multiple lines drawn, sometimes overlapping each other.
QGIS shows the label of the different lines next to each other. (labels contain length of the line, type, startpoint, endpoint)
[image]

Is there a way to show them below each other instead?
I tried to concatenate the labels, but then all labels from all lines of the layer will be shown at every point.
Since the lines have no common start or endpoint, I can't apply any useful filter to the concatenation.
[image]

So I want the labels from the first picture, placed below each other like in the second picture.
Any suggestions?